# Continue query exception when fill(null) used

Tags: influxdb

This continue query:

*select mean(elapsed) as average, percentile(elapsed,95) as percentile_95, max(elapsed) as maximum from /^Jmeter.*/ group by time(1s) fill(null) into 1sec.timing.:series_name backfill(false)*

cause to error:

[2015/07/01 08:05:38 IDT] EROR Couldn't write data for continuous query: %!(EXTRA *errors.errorStr
ing=proto: Marshal called with nil)

and doesnt works.

Without fill(null) the CQ works fine, but i need to fill the intervals in series.

Is some workaround exists?

Answer (score 0):

In InfluxDB (v0.8), a continuous query inserts the results of each run of the query into a series. If a run of the CQ produces no results, nothing is written to the series.

By definition, a `FILL(null)` returns no result so nothing is written to the series for that run of the CQ.

To accomplish what I think you're trying to do, query the series created by the CQ with a `FILL(null)` and a `GROUP BY time(1s)`. For example,

```
SELECT average, percentile_95, maximum FROM 1sec.timing.:series_name GROUP BY time(1s) FILL(null)
```